# SQL Server query xml attribute for an element value

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

Sorry if this is somewhere else, I have found a lot of similar examples but I have been unable to get it working with my data. 2 days later and I need an answer :(

Basically have a SQL Server table with a column containing XML data. This data contains values I need to extract.

Here is my XML.

```
  <CustomFields xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.kaseya.com/vsa/2007/12/ServiceDeskDefinition.xsd">
    <Field fieldName="AutoCategory">Event Log</Field>
    <Field fieldName="SType">Event Log</Field>
    <Field fieldName="STag1">AgentGuid</Field>
    <Field fieldName="STag2">AlertRegistrationId</Field>
    <Field fieldName="STag3">LogType</Field>
    <Field fieldName="SValue1">619764177412541</Field>
    <Field fieldName="SValue2">104</Field>
    <Field fieldName="SValue3">1380569194</Field>
    <Field fieldName="SdTicketId">RPSv1006330</Field>
    <Field fieldName="AgentName">bla bla</Field>
    <Field fieldName="MachineGroupGuid">86115414719112271316891312</Field>
    <Field fieldName="OrgFk">59165166782128125214185317</Field>
    <Field fieldName="GuidAgent">619764177412541</Field>
    <Field fieldName="AlertCount">0</Field>
    <Field fieldName="TicketTitle">bla bla</Field>
    <Field fieldName="LegacyId">152262</Field>
    <Field fieldName="LegacyRef">152262</Field>
    <Field fieldName="CwStatus">2</Field>
    <Field fieldName="CwTicketId">89495</Field>
</CustomFields>
```

I need to be able to pull out the value associated to the `CwTicketId` field name.

So in essence, I want to look through the XML to find the node with `fieldName = "CwTicketId"` and to return `89495` or equivalent value.

Below is the code I have come up with myself, which pulls values out, but the problem is sometimes the XML is ordered differently, so the values are not always on the line that I have specified, hence it returns in accurate data.

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT N'http://www.kaseya.com/vsa/2007/12/ServiceDeskDefinition.xsd')
SELECT 
    ref as ServiceDeskID, 
    sdSummary as ServiceDeskSummary,
    customFields.value('(/CustomFields/Field/node())[17]', 'varchar(100)') as LegacyIDTicketing,
    customFields.value('(/CustomFields/Field/node())[19]', 'varchar(100)') as CWIDTicketing
FROM 
    [ksubscribers].[kasadmin].[SDIncident]
```

The second value I also need, but if i can figure out how to pull one value out, I can duplicate for the other.

Hope someone can help as I have started ripping my hair out!

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT N'http://www.kaseya.com/vsa/2007/12/ServiceDeskDefinition.xsd')
select
    T.C.value('data(.)', 'nvarchar(128)')
from [YOUR_TABLE] as Y
    outer apply Y.[YOUR_XML_COLUMN].nodes('/CustomFields/Field[@fieldName="CwTicketId"]') as T(C)
```

Comment: Hi Roman, thanks for the VERY quick reply. Can you help me understand how to use this? Currently I was pulling the XML directly from the record, I don't understand the T.C.value and @XML.nodes. Appologies but I am a complete SQL noob.

Comment: I don't think I can explain better than msdn :) Basically you need to read about reading XML from SQL. Also you need to read about xpath and xquery - you'll need it to read data from XML. I've changed a query a little bit - like you have a table and xml column in this table

Comment: Thanks Roman, your changes were enough to allow me to get things working!

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT N'http://www.kaseya.com/vsa/2007/12/ServiceDeskDefinition.xsd')
SELECT 
    ref as ServiceDeskID, 
    sdSummary as ServiceDeskSummary,
    CwTicketID = customFields.value('(/CustomFields/Field[@fieldName="CwTicketId"]/text())[1]', 'int')
FROM  
   [ksubscribers].[kasadmin].[SDIncident]
```

This selected the `<Field>` node that has the `CwTicketId` as its field name attribute - and this will work always, no matter how the XML and its nodes are ordered (as long as the `fieldName` **value** stays `CwTicketId`).

Comment: Thanks Marc, your also works very well! Extremely impressed by the speed and quality of this site!