# SQL Server generating XML with generic field elements

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm basically trying to reverse what this question is asking...
[SQL Server query xml attribute for an element value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913724/sql-server-query-xml-attribute-for-an-element-value)

I need to produce a result set of "row" elements that contain a group of "field" elements with an attribute that defines the key.

```
<resultset statement="" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<row>
    <field name="id">1</field>
    <field name="version”>0</field>
    <field name="property">My Movie</field>
    <field name="release_date">2012-01-01</field>
    <field name="territory_code”>FR</field>
    <field name="territory_description">FRANCE</field>
    <field name="currency_code”>EUR</field>
</row>
<row>
    <field name="id">2</field>
    <field name="version”>0</field>
    <field name="property">My Sequel</field>
    <field name="release_date">2014-03-01</field>
    <field name="territory_code”>UK</field>
    <field name="territory_description">United Kingdom</field>
    <field name="currency_code”>GBP</field>
</row>
</resultset>
```

I've got a query that returns this...

```
<resultset statement="" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<row>
    <id>1</id>
    <version>0</version>
    <property>My Movie</property>
    <release_date>2012-01-01</release_date>
    <territory_code>FR</territory_code>
    <territory_description>FRANCE</territory_description>
    <currency_code>EUR</currency_code>
</row>
<row>
    <id>2</id>
    <version>0</version>
    <property>My Sequel</property>
    <release_date>2014-03-01</release_date>
    <territory_code>UK</territory_code>
    <territory_description>UNITED KINGDOM</territory_description>
    <currency_code>GBP</currency_code>
</row>
</resultset>
```

Using `FOR XML PATH ('row'), ROOT ('resultset')` in my SQL statement.

What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a bit involved in SQL Server - the normal behavior is what you're seeing - the column names will be used as XML element names.

If you *really* want all XML elements to be named the same, you'll have to use code something like this:

```sql
SELECT
    'id' AS 'field/@name',
    id AS 'field',
    '',
    'version' AS 'field/@name',
    version AS 'field',
    '',
    'property' AS 'field/@name',
    property AS 'field',
    '',
    ... and so on ....
FROM Person.Person
FOR XML PATH('row'),ROOT('resultset')
```

This is necessary to make sure the column name is used as the `name` attribute on the `<field>` element, and the empty string are necessary so that the SQL XML parser doesn't get confused about which `name` attribute belongs to what element......

Comment: I was afraid something like that was going to be the answer! It worked like a charm though, thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without having to specify the columns as constants and that will allow you to also use `select *`. It is a bit more complicated than the answer provided by marc_s and it will be quite a lot slower to execute.

```sql
select (
       select T.X.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(128)') as '@name',
              T.X.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as '*'
       from C.X.nodes('/X/*') as T(X)
       for xml path('field'), type
       )
from (
     select (
            select T.*
            for xml path('X'), type
            ) as X
     from dbo.YourTable as T
     ) as C
for xml path('row'), root('resultset')
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/95f2f/1)

The query creates a derived table where each row has a XML that looks something like this:

```xml
<X>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <Col1>1</Col1>
  <Col2>2014-08-21</Col2>
</X>
```

That XML is then shredded using `nodes()` and `local-name(.)` to create the shape you want.

Answer (score -1):

Your SELECT statement needs to look something like this

```
SELECT
    'id' AS [field/@name],
    id AS field,
    'version' AS [field/@name],
    version AS field,
    'property' AS [field/@name],
    property AS field,
    'release_date' AS [field/@name],
    release_date AS field,
    'territory_code' AS [field/@name],
    territory_code AS field,
    'territory_description' AS [field/@name],
    territory_description AS field,
    'currency_code' AS [field/@name],
    currency_code AS field
```

Comment: This will **not** work as is..... you'll get an error: `Msg 6852, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 - Attribute-centric column 'field/@name' must not come after a non-attribute-centric sibling in XML hierarchy in FOR XML PATH.`

Comment: You're right. I wasn't able to run the statement against anything to validate syntax.