# TSQL FOR XML Formatting

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, for-xml-path

I have a table that I would like to convert into an XML format. The table is called tempTable and holds data as such:

```
REF     DESC     QTY
100001  Normal   1
100002  OOH      1
```

I need to create the XML in this given format:

```
<row>
  <LIN NUM="1">
    <FLD NAME="REF">100001</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="DES">Normal</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="QTY">1</FLD>
  </LIN>
  <LIN NUM="2">
    <FLD NAME="REF">100002</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="DES">OOH</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="QTY">1</FLD>
  </LIN>
</row>
```

I have tried the below code:

```
SET @line = (SELECT '1' AS '@NUM', REF AS 'REF', DES AS 'DES', QTY AS 'QTY' FROM tempTable WHERE ORDER= @ORDER
FOR XML PATH('LIN'))

SELECT @line
FOR XML PATH
```

However this produces:

```
<row>
  <LIN NUM="1">
    <REF>100001</REF>
    <DES>Normal</DES>
    <QTY>1</QTY>
  </LIN>
  <LIN NUM="1">
    <REF>100002</REF>
    <DES>OOH</DES>
    <QTY>1</QTY>
  </LIN>
</row>
```

Does anyone know how I can:

- A) Change the 'LIN' 'NUM' attribute to be incremental based on the number of
  records for that order?
- B) Add the 'Name' attribute to the 'LIN'    details and change the
  field names to 'FLD'. When I try to change the    name to 'FLD' it
  concats the values onto a single node, as such:

  ```
  <row>
    <LIN NUM="1">
      <FLD>100001Normal1</FLD>
    </LIN>
    <LIN NUM="1">
      <FLD>100002OOH1</FLD>
    </LIN>
  </row>
  ```

I assume if I can add the 'NAME' attribute that would separate out the values?

Any advice/help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
declare @tempTable table (Ref int, Des varchar(100), Qty int)
insert into @tempTable values (100001, 'Normal', 1), (100002, 'OOH', 1)

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Ref) AS '@NUM',
     'REF' AS 'FLD/@NAME', REF AS 'FLD', '',
     'DES' AS 'FLD/@NAME', DES AS 'FLD', '',
     'QTY' AS 'FLD/@NAME', QTY AS 'FLD'

FROM @tempTable 
FOR XML PATH('LIN'), ROOT ('row')
```

produces:

```
<row>
  <LIN NUM="1">
    <FLD NAME="REF">100001</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="DES">Normal</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="QTY">1</FLD>
  </LIN>
  <LIN NUM="2">
    <FLD NAME="REF">100002</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="DES">OOH</FLD>
    <FLD NAME="QTY">1</FLD>
  </LIN>
</row>
```

with a little help from https://stackoverflow.com/a/25412657/4473405 because without the empty strings between the node and the attribute in the select, SQL Server gives an error:

> Attribute-centric column 'FLD/@NAME' must not come after a non-attribute-centric sibling in XML hierarchy in FOR XML PATH.

EDIT: as has been mentioned in the comments, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29234102/569436) explains why the empty quote trick works.

To summarize:

- in `FOR XML PATH`, columns without a name become text nodes

  - `NULL` or `''` therefore become empty text nodes
  - you can convert a named column to an unnamed one by using `AS *`
  - this helps to separate the previously output nodes from the next one, so that SQL Server knows e.g. to start a new element for the next column. Otherwise, it gets confused when for example the attribute already exists on what it thinks is the "current" element

Comment: I hadn't known the trick with the empty string and was just puzzling around with this. Nice...

Comment: @Shnugo Something about what the trick actually does. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29234102/569436

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (ref varchar(10), descr varchar(10), qty varchar(3))
insert into @t
values('100001', 'Normal', '1'),('10002','OOH','1')

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.ref) AS '@NUM',
(SELECT 'REF' AS 'FLD/@NAME'
 ,ref AS 'FLD'
FROM @t AS FLD
WHERE FLD.ref = a.ref
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE),
(SELECT 'DESCR' AS 'FLD/@DESCR'
 ,descr AS 'FLD'
FROM @t AS FLD
WHERE FLD.ref = a.ref
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE),
(SELECT 'QTY' AS 'FLD/@QTY'
 ,QTY AS 'FLD'
FROM @t AS FLD
WHERE FLD.ref = a.ref
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
FROM @t AS a
FOR XML PATH('LIN'), ROOT('row')
```

Comment: Could you explain this?