# Do I need /text() when selecting an attribute value from an XML column?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've seen [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12914072/157247) doing it like this, with `/text()`:

```
SELECT someColumn.value('(/someElement[@someAttribute="some value"]/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
FROM   SomeTable
```

and I've seen some (including [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx)) leaving off the `/text()` step:

```
SELECT someColumn.value('(/someElement[@someAttribute="some value"])[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
-- No /text() here ------------------------------------------------^
FROM   SomeTable
```

Both forms work with my data. Does it matter from any perspective other than style? Such as performance, or assumptions, ...

Update: I've run both queries in the same batch with "actual execution plan" turned on, using a simple synthetic example with ~1 million rows (limiting to 10 rows by PK), and the actual execution plans *are* different, but I'm no expert at reading execution plans. It also consistently claims that the version with `/text()` is 54% of the total and the version without is 46%. This suggests there's a difference of some kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference, but apparently you don't encounter it in your data. Here is an example:

```
declare @x xml;

set @x = '
<Item Id="1">Just a text</Item>
<Item Id="2">
    <SubItem Id="247">Subitem text.</SubItem>
Text and some extra</Item>
';

select @x.value('/Item[@Id="1"][1]', 'varchar(max)') as [No text works],
    @x.value('/Item[@Id="2"][1]', 'varchar(max)') as [More complex case],
    @x.value('(/Item[@Id="2"]/text())[1]', 'varchar(max)') as [Text fixes it];
```